# ¿Cómo hacer la conexión a mysql aplicando POO?

Tags: php, mysql

Actualmente hago mi conexión como muestro en el ejemplo, pero deseo pasarme a POO. He visitado muchos foros e incluso el manual de PHP pero me confundo más ya que solo encuentro partes que no logro entender.

Fichero > conecta.php

```
$dbhost ="localhost";
$dbusuario ="usuario";
$dbpassword ="xxxxxxx";
$db = "usuarios";


$conecta = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbusuario, $dbpassword);
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8',  $conexion);
mysql_select_db($db,$conecta);
```

y la implemento así:

```
include("conecta.php");

$sql_q = mysql_query("select * from datos");
$res_q      = mysql_fetch_array($sql_q);
$cantidad   = $res_q["cantidad"];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mi sugerencia es que comiences con algún manual de PHP POO (te dejo un [link](http://www.codigo-facil.com/es/poo-php-clases.php)) ya que no solo tendrás que entender la conexión, si no que además deberás crear, instanciar e implementar clases. Respondiendo a tu consulta, hay varias maneras y seguro que todas son válidas (cuando son correctas) pero te puedo ayudar poniendo un ejemplo de como yo lo hago.

**Archivo conexion.php**

```
class Conexion extends PDO
 { 
   private $tipo_de_base    = 'mysql';          /**< Indica el tipo de motor de datos */
   private $host            = 'localhost';      /**< Indica el host */
   private $nombre_de_base = 'test';            /**< Indica el nombre de la base de datos */
   private $usuario         = 'root';           /**< Indica el nombre de usuario de la base de datos */
   private $contrasena      = 'vertrigo';       /**< Indica la contraseña de usuario de la base de datos */


   /**
     * @brief crea la conexión PDO.
    */  
   public function __CONSTRUCT() {

      try{
         parent::__CONSTRUCT($this->tipo_de_base.':host='.$this->host.';dbname='.$this->nombre_de_base, $this->usuario, $this->contrasena);

      }catch(PDOException $e){
         echo 'Ha surgido un error y no se puede conectar a la base de datos. Detalle: ' . $e->getMessage();
         exit;
      }
   } 
 }
```

**Ejemplo de implementación**:

```
function validarUsuario($rut, $clave, $objUsr)
    {

        try{

            require_once ('conexion.php');

            $pdo = new Conexion();
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $pdo->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");   

            $stm    = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE rut = ? and Clave = ? ");
            $stm->execute(array($rut,$clave));
            $r = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

            if($r){

                $objUsr->__SET('id', $r->id);
                $objUsr->__SET('Nombre', $r->Nombre);
                $objUsr->__SET('Apellido', $r->Apellido);
                $objUsr->__SET('Sexo', $r->Sexo);
                $objUsr->__SET('FechaNacimiento', date("d-m-Y", strtotime($r->FechaNacimiento)));


                return $objUsr;

            }else{

                return false;   

            }

        }catch (Exception $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Hay que considerar que esta implementación utiliza la clase usuario por lo que esta función se llamaría así:

```
require_once("clases/usuario.cls.php");
$objUsr         = new Usuario();
$usr_ok         = validarUsuario($rut,$clave,$objUsr); // $rut y $clave llegan de una página de formulario.
```

Para comprender mejor el ejemplo pondré la clase usuario y tendrás un ejemplo completo:

**Archivo usuario.cls.php**

```
class Usuario
{
    private $id;
    private $Rut;
    private $Nombre;
    private $Apellido;
    private $Sexo;
    private $FechaNacimiento;
    private $Clave;

    public function __GET($k){
        return $this->$k;
    }
    public function __SET($k, $v){
        return $this->$k = $v; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Funciona pero seguire tu consejo. hay muchas cosas que no se por que funcionan. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

No puedes hacer POO con las funciones `mysql_*`, de hecho, deberías dejar de usarlas por diferentes motivos:

- Se han dejado de desarrollar.
- Están deprecadas a partir de la versión 5.5 de PHP (y eliminadas completamente en la 7).
- No permiten orientación a objetos.
- Son inseguras por naturaleza (p.e.: no permiten consultas preparadas/parametrizadas).

Si quieres una opción POO, deberías usar `MySQLi` o `PDO` (si estás acostumbrado a `mysql_*`, la primera te resultará más sencilla, aunque a mí personalmente me gusta más PDO, pero eso es elección propia).

Aquí dejo un ejemplo de cómo sería con MySQLi:

```
$dbhost ="localhost";
$dbusuario ="usuario";
$dbpassword ="xxxxxxx";
$db = "usuarios";

$conecta = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbusuario, $dbpassword);
$conecta->set_charset("utf8");
$conecta->select_db($conecta);
```

Y con PDO sería algo como esto:

```
$conecta = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$db;charset=utf8", $dbusuario, $dbpassword);
```

con la especificación de la base de datos y el charset directamente en la cadena de conexión.